# How to Find Stack Overflow in Microcontrollers using C in Run Time

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am creating the application on STM32 microcontroller. I am using some library stack. Above that stack, I am using my application. I have two questions:

1. How can I detect and handle the stack over flow in runtime. Because I don't know how much memory that library is using.
2. How can I detect and handle the stack over flow in runtime if I am developing the code from the scratch. I read some where we have to maintain some count for each declaration. Is this correct way or any standard way to find it.

Comment: If the stack is corrupted in any way, there's not really much you *can* do, except a reset.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But before allocating, is there any Method to find a stack overflow. So that, I can log a error that system restarted due to stack over flow.

Comment: Which operating system (on the embedded board)? Which cross-compiler?

Comment: Related: make sure you have memory-mapped the stack so that it overflows relatively harmlessly into non-RAM instead of going Toyota all over the place, [see this article](http://embeddedgurus.com/state-space/2014/02/are-we-shooting-ourselves-in-the-foot-with-stack-overflow/).

Comment: If the stack is statically allocated during linking (by the linker script) then for simple cases the linker will complain that the amount of stack used is larger than the allocated segment. The simple case most notably being that some function have an array to large to fit. Other than that is really very hard to debug stack errors, but it is possible using a debugger connected to the JTAG port (if you have one). You also need to be able to identify and replicate lockups and crashes and unknown reboots which are the typical signs of stack errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are limited to your device and no "high sophisticated" tools available, you could at least try "the old way". A simple stack guard may help. Somewhere in your code (depends on the tools you use), there must be the definition of the stack area. Something similar to:

```
.equ         stacksize, 1024

stack:       .space   stacksize,0
```

(gnu as syntax, your's might be different)

with your device's startup code somewhere initializing the stack register to the top address of the `stack` area.

A stack guard would then just add a "magic number" to the stack top and bottom:

```
.equ         stackmagic,0xaffeaffe
.equ         stacksize, 1024


stacktop:    .int     stackmagic
stack:       .space   stacksize,0
stackbottom: .int     stackmagic
```

with some code at least periodically checking (e.g. in a timer interrupt routine or - if available - in your debugger) if the `stackmagic` values are still there.

Comment: I understood the Method. But I didn't get why stack guard add magic number. What does it mean?. Periodically, what it will check, stack size?. If yes, how it will increase.

Comment: the stack guard just sets a known value to start and end of the stack. You can then check if these "magic numbers" get overwritten which would indicate a stack over- or underflow.

Comment: mfro is using the term "[magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)" to refer to "Distinctive unique values that are unlikely to be mistaken for other meanings".  0xA5A5 and 0xDEADBEEF are common examples of magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If your software is not tiny, I would first try to debug most of it on your laptop or desktop or tablet (perhaps running Linux, because it has good tools and very standard compliant compilers, similar to the cross-compiler you are using). Then you can profit from tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilation options like `-Wall -Wextra -g -fsanitize=address` etc....

You might store an approximation of the top of stack at start of your `main` function (e.g. by doing `extern int* start_top_of_stack;`  then `int i=0; start_top_of_stack= &i;` near beginning of your `main` function. You could then have some local `int j=0;` in several functions and check at start of them that `&j - start_top_of_stack` is not too big.

But there is [no silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet). I am just suggesting a trick.

If your application is critical to the point of accepting costly development efforts, you could use some [formal method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods)  & [source static program analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools (e.g. [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/), or make your own using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)). If you are cross-compiling with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you might want to use `-Wstack-usage=`*some length* and/or `-fstack-usage`  to check that every call frame is not too big, or to compute manually the required stack depth.